# Setting a raw binary environment variable in herkou

Tags: bash, heroku, character-encoding, environment-variables

I'm trying to set an environment variable in heroku with a binary value.

e.g. in Python 2:

```
open('x.txt','w').write('a\x89b')
```

followed by bash:

```
heroku config:set TEST=`cat x.txt`
```

Unfortunately, instead of setting the environment variable to a 3-byte value, heroku switches the `\x89` byte with the UTF-8 [replacement character](http://apps.timwhitlock.info/unicode/inspect?s=%EF%BF%BD) `\xef\xbf\xbd`.

I guess the problem is that the heroku CLI expects a UTF-8 encoded string. How is it possible to hand a raw binary string instead to heroku, via the CLI or otherwise?

Comment: I just tested this with `TEST=$(cat x.txt)` and `hexdump -C <<< "$TEST"` and the `\x89b` seems unmodified, so probably a pure heroku problem.

Comment: Indeed - locally, it works well. Somewhere on the way there is probably some ruby/javascript/heroku specific encoding issue. I'm just not very familiar with either of those :)

Comment: me neither, sorry, I'm just good on the Bash/Linux part :-)

Comment: This could be a dumb question. Did you try writing to the file in binary mode using Python ?

Comment: It's not dumb, but it also doesn't make any difference :)

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? :)